# No CSS styles while visiting from China

Tags: javascript, css

we have a problem at one of our sites. Visitors from China see it without css files, just the html. What could be possible reson for this? 
Why only in China? Are there any restrictions? Maybe for js or something?

Comment: Do you use any external CSS or JS? (As example the ajax library hosted at Google)

Comment: Maybe your css is loaded from a server that gets blocked by China's firewall?

Comment: Without more info this is impossible to answer

Comment: @EricHotinger, for that OP needs to visit China ;)

Comment: This might be of use: [Website Test behind the Great Firewall of China](http://www.websitepulse.com/help/testtools.china-test.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answers, guys. I believe you right about external resources, checking now. @Carpetsmoker helpful link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be a source file which is fetched from another server which gets blocked by China.

I suggest you to download the file and put it on your own server and use it from there and manually update it periodically, since your server is not blocked you should keep everything internally, no problems should occur.

Comment: Thanks, that what I think it was. I'll check all external sources.